# How to transmit Django variables to a Js file

Tags: javascript, django, django-views

As you can see in the code below, I have imported a `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/posts_lazy_loading.js' %}"></script>` to my Index.html.
But there are Django variables in that JS file. like: `{{ sizes }}` and `{{ urlsPosts }}`, they go from Views.py to the Index.html.

Unfortunately Django doesn't see these variables in the JS file if I keep the JS as a separate file.
If I copy paste the JS right to the HTML without separating - everything works well.
How can I include these Django variables into the separate Js file?

Index.html:

```
<html>
    {% load static %}
    {% include 'head.html' %}
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>
    </body>
    <footer>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/posts_lazy_loading.js' %}"></script> 
    </footer>
</html>
```

Views.py:

```
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    sizes = ''
    urlsPosts = ''

    for i in range(0, len(posts)):
        if i == len(posts):
            sizes = sizes +  str(posts[i].thumbnail.width) + 'x'
            sizes = sizes +  str(posts[i].thumbnail.height)
            urlsPosts = urlsPosts + posts[i].thumbnail.url
        else:
            sizes = sizes +  str(posts[i].thumbnail.width) + 'x'
            sizes = sizes +  str(posts[i].thumbnail.height) + ' '
            urlsPosts = urlsPosts + posts[i].thumbnail.url + ' '

    return render(request,'index.html',{'posts':posts, 'sizes':sizes, 'urlsPosts':urlsPosts)
```

posts_lazy_loading.js:

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('cover_main_page'),
    posts = document.getElementsByClassName('post'),
    descriptions = document.getElementsByClassName('description'),
    description_height = descriptions[0].clientHeight;
    post_content = document.getElementsByClassName('post_content'),
    loading = document.getElementsByClassName('dots_portoflio'),
    sizes = "{{ sizes }}",
    sizeslist = sizes.split(" "),
    urlsPosts = "{{ urlsPosts }}",
    urlslist = urlsPosts.split(' '),
    ratios = [],
    viewport_width = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    newwidth = 0,
    margin = 3, //each post has 3vw margin left and 3vw margin right
    mobile = 0,
    mobilewidth = 94;

    .... a lot of code here ....
```

Comment: Convert your plain js code into function, call it from the template and pass your arguments. Or better split your single view into multiple: template-view and api-views. So api-views would return JSON objects for your js script. Also unclear why wouldn't you just generate whole page using Django template engine/syntax only.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, django will generate this line as follows:

It won't open the JS as this will ask the browser to load the JS, to use django inside your JS, you have one of two options

1. Use {%include 'JSFILE'%} but in this case, your JS file shall be in the templates folder
2. Put the JS code itself in your HTML template.

Comment: Thank you Mohamed - I will keep it in mind now. It makes sense. Have a wonderful day!